# How to display indented xml inside a django webpage?

Tags: python, xml, django, jinja2

In my Django application, I call an external API, which returns XML. I would like to display this "minified" response as an indented multiline string on the page (a plus would be syntax highlighting). I tried to process the string in Python with toprettyxml() from xml.dom.minidom, and a few things with ElementTree, but it does not play along the Jinja2 rendering well (line breaks disappear and I only get a one line string, displayed inside `<pre>` tags).

What's the recommended way to display such code excerpt?

Should I use client-side rendering? Then, which library should I use?

Django version: 1.11.2
Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 1):

This isn't anything to do with Python or Jinja2, but just down to how browsers render text within HTML.

If you want to preserve spacing and indentation, you need to wrap your content with `<pre>...</pre>` tags.

Comment: I should have added the precision: it is wrapped inside `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Jinja would not remove line breaks, so something else is going on. Can you provide an example of your view and template?